# have any one used * custom option in selenium rc

Tags: selenium-rc

i have 2 firefox version and i need to start particular version using
custom is that possible.

Comment: i tried this but extra parameter is passing like below,
http://www.google.com/selenium-server/co...debugMode=false

Code :

RemoteControlConfiguration rc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
rc.setPort(4444);
seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer(rc);
seleniumServer.start();
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*custom \"C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe\"",
"http://www.google.com/");

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.

Instead of running the server from the command prompt - create one new class which will create instance of `SeleniumServerControl()` and then in the start function you specify the firefox installation directory path.

Something similar to this.

```
RemoteControlConfiguration settings = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
File f = new File("C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/");
settings.setFirefoxProfileTemplate(f);
settings.setReuseBrowserSessions(true);
settings.setSingleWindow(true);
settings.setJettyThreads(100);
settings.setPort(4444);
settings.setDebugMode(true);
if (!serverWorks) {
    try {
         server = new SeleniumServer(settings);
         server.start();
     serverWorks = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And in `setUp()` method specify full path of firefox.exe

Comment: if i use custom as you said some extra parameters are passing in url like below in browser , selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html? sessionId=dc91ae43b4754f87a25d4718feeb&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=http%3A %2F%2Ftest.com&debugMode=false   and it doesnt work

Comment: i want to use * custom because i have to firefox version and i want to start with particular version

Comment: I was talking about running it using selenium RC.

Comment: iam also using selenium rc and starting server from code,but if i use as above some extra parameters are passing in url like below in browser , selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html? sessionId=dc91ae43b4754f87a25d4718feeb&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=http%3A %2F%2Ftest.com&debugMode=false and it doesnt work

Comment: can any one help me on this??